# Как задеплоить war file с github через jenkins в tomcat

Tags: github, tomcat, virtualbox, jenkins

У меня есть проект на гитхабе, гитхаб связан с jenkins по SSH, как Дженкинсом задеплоить проект в tomcat
Tomcat 10
Дженкинс 2.4

Оба находятся на виртуалке virtual box
Пробовал плагин внутри Jenkins deploy in container но он для 9 tomcat

Единственное решение вижу через pipeline но я в этом новичок

Еще пробовал war файл Дженкинса задеплоить в tomcat но tomcat не может включить Дженкинса в силу разных версий

Что делать?

Comment: https://www.cyberithub.com/deploy-application-war-file-to-tomcat-using-jenkins-simple-steps/

Comment: @nexoma пожалуйста обратите внимание на 5 шаг в статье что вы кинули там просят скачать plugin deploy to container для 8 томката, у меня томкат 10! он не работает для 10 версии томката

Comment: ну, тогда просто скопируйте war в каталог развертывания tomcat

Comment: При помощи нейросети написал себе скрипт для pipeline теперь все работает залью решение в ближайшие дни

Comment: @nexoma просто задание со стажировки, нужно не в ручную war файл добавлять а именно чтобы jenkins его в tomcat деплоил

Comment: да поставьте простое cp или copy (linux или windows), если локально, вообще без проблем. каталог развертывания же знаете? для межмашинного - scp, ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, плагин который имеется у Jenkins deploy in container придуман для tomcat 9 версии, выше этой он подключаться не будет.

Моим решением стало написать PipeLine код, ч не стал долго вникать в его синтаксис и напороться пришла нейронка которая написала его вместо меня.

А код для деплоя ниже:

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            // Checkout the code repository
            checkout scm
        }
    }
    
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            // Build the war file
             sh 'mvn clean package'
        }
    }
    
    stage('Deploy') {
        environment {
            TOMCAT_HOME = '/opt/tomcat'
            WAR_FILE = 'target/HelloWorldServlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war'
        }
        
        steps {
            // Stop Tomcat
            sh "${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/shutdown.sh"
            
            // Remove existing war file and deployed application
            sh "rm -rf ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/HelloWorldServlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT*"
            
            // Copy the new war file to Tomcat webapps directory
            sh "cp ${WAR_FILE} ${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/myapp.war"
            
            // Start Tomcat
            sh "${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/startup.sh"
        }
    }
    
    stage('Verify') {
        steps {
            // Wait for Tomcat to start
            sh "sleep 30"
            
            // Verify if the application is deployed successfully
            sh "curl -s http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet-1.0-SNAPSHOT/"
        }
    }
}

post {
    always {
        // Cleanup any leftover files after deployment
        sh "rm -rf ${WAR_FILE}"
    }
}
```

}